# answering questions in a PhD proposal template

Tags: research-proposal

I have received an email from a university in the Netherlands in which the professor asked four candidates, including me, to write a proposal. In that proposal, I am asked to answer some questions. one question that I should answer is:

> Statement of a provisional timetable

I do not know how to answer this request. Please help me with this.

Comment: Hi Mohamad! Would you please clarify what is exactly not clear about the question? Are you applying for a PhD position?

Answer (score 4):

A "provisional timetable" is an estimate, hopefully informed, about how long the work is expected to take. It can be detailed, breaking down stages of the work, or not. Detailed estimates are probably better.

The timetable is *provisional*, however, since research *results* can't be scheduled. If you are dealing with the unknown, it is impossible, in general, to say in advance when it will become known.

Comment: So, is only writing that "hopefully it will take 4 years" sufficient to answer this question?

Comment: @MohamadGhoreishi You should try to give more information with more confidence than that. As Buffy says, you want to break down stages of your work in as much detail as possible (at least year-by-year but finer-grained if possible). Everyone understands these are estimates and can change, so don't feel you are locking yourself into anything. But the point is to show that you've thought through what your research will look like over the next 4 years. Writing one sentence like "hopefully I'll finish my work in 4 years" will not convey a positive impression.